# What is the error in syntax in python code for MySQL connector?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector-python

This is a python code to create table in MySQL through *mysql-connector*. But it is showing **ProgrammingError** while assigning *datetime* datatype to field.

```
import mysql.connector as sqltor
from datetime import datetime
mycon = sqltor.connect(host='localhost',database='linkbook',user='root',passwd='****')
cursor = mycon.cursor()

cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS account\
               (UserID varchar(10) Primary Key, \
               Firstname varchar(15), \
               Lastname varchar(15), \
               Password varchar(10), \
               Links_Posted int DEFAULT 0)")

cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS linkbook \
               (UserID varchar(10), \
               Links varchar(50), \
               Description varchar(100), \
               Tag varchar(15), \
               date_time datetime)")

cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS edu_links\
               (UserID varchar(10) \
               Link varchar(50), \
               Description varchar(100), \
               date_time datetime)")   #Error in this line
Exception has occurred: ProgrammingError
1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Link varchar(50),                Description varchar(100),                date_t' at line 1
```

Kindly help in getting the right syntax. Thank You.

Comment: You missed comma in this line: `UserID varchar(10)`. It should be `UserID varchar(10), \` in last `cursor.execute()` method.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. Can't believe i didn't noticed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you will look closely at the last cursor.execute method call, then you will see that you are missing a comma after **UserID varchar(10)**. This then changes you final cursor.execute call with the following parameter value:

```
    cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS edu_links\
           (UserID varchar(10), \
           Link varchar(50), \
           Description varchar(100), \
           date_time datetime)")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy. :) seriously how much a small syntax error can trouble one